# Estimating a random effect nested within a fixed effect for a linear mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, nested-data

```
politeness=read.csv("http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/politeness_data.csv")

library(lme4)

mod<- lmer(frequency~ scenario+gender+ (1|attitude), data = politeness)

mod1<- lmer(frequency~ scenario+gender+ (1|gender/attitude), data = politeness)
```

Attitude is nested into gender but it returns a warning:

```
Warning message: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), optpar,ctrl=controlcheckConv, : Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio - Rescale variables?
```

How to fix? 
Here i have to consider gender as a fixed effect.

Comment: What's the warning?

Comment: Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?

Comment: Are the variables highly correlated? If the answer is no then try rescaling the variables, for ex. with standardization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have stated that `gender` is a fixed effect, which makes complete sense. However, `(1|gender/attitude)` makes no sense because this is treating `gender` as random, which it isn't - it's fixed.

Since there are (presumably) only 2 levels of `gender`, the software is trying to estimate a variance for a random variable (even though we already know it is fixed) from only 2 observations. This may be the root of the problem you have encountered.

Note: `attitude` is not nested within `gender`. To be nested, each level of `attitude` would be associated with only a single level of `gender` which presumably is not the case. Even if this condition was satisfied, to treat `gender` as random makes no sense whatsoever.

If you get the warning with the first model:

```
mod <- lmer(frequency ~ scenario + gender+ (1|attitude), data = politeness)
```

then try standardising `frequency` and (depending on it's type) `scenario`. If it only happens in the 2nd model, there is no problem, the 2nd model makes no sense.

Comment: Yijkl =µ+ δl+ βi(l) + αj + γk + αγjk + єijkl

Yijkl is the response due to subject i, treatment j, and Period k, and sequence l;

µ is an overall mean;

δ is a fixed effect due to sequence l;

βi(l) is a random effect due to subject i nested within sequence l; are independent;

αj is a fixed effect due to treatment j;

γk  is a fixed effect due to Period k; 

αγjk   is a fixed interaction effect due to treatment j and Period k;

Comment: єijkl  is the random error and are independent; 

The random components єijkl and βi(l) are independent

For such a model how to estimate βi(l)??

Comment: @ashraful please post those comments as a new question.